# Convert string Y.m.d H:i:s to timestamp Y-m-d H:i:s in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, timestamp

For example I have this string "2015.02.10 01:24:13". And I need it to be converted to timestamp format 2015-02-10 01:24:13. 
I tried this

```
$dtime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s",$new_data['query_start_date']); 
$post->query_start_date = $dtime->getTimestamp();
```

But it didnt work.

Comment: timestamps don't actually have  format; they're signed integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It didn't work

Its because you were creating a wrong format for the date i.e.

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s",$new_data['query_start_date']);
```

should be

```
$dtime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y.m.d H:i:s",$new_data['query_start_date']);
                                     ^^^^^// Changed the date format as you've defined i.e. 2015.02.10 01:24:13
```

And for formatting your date you need to use `format` method of `DateTime` class like as

```
$post->query_start_date = $dtime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Just to complete the answer: and then you just format it the way you want with $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked.